Somekhos's opinion "money which is in dispute - is to be split" vs Beit Shammai
We know that Somekhos holds that (Baba Kamma 5:1 - Gmara ad loc):

ממון המוטל בספק חולקין


Property of uncertain ownership is divided by the two parties

However, in Baba Batra 9:8:

נָפַל הַבַּיִת עָלָיו וְעַל אָבִיו אוֹ עָלָיו וְעַל מוֹרִישָׁיו, וְהָיְתָה עָלָיו כְּתֻבַּת אִשָּׁה וּבַעַל חוֹב, יוֹרְשֵׁי הָאָב אוֹמְרִים, הַבֵּן מֵת רִאשׁוֹן וְאַחַר כָּךְ מֵת הָאָב, בַּעֲלֵי הַחוֹב אוֹמְרִים, הָאָב מֵת רִאשׁוֹן וְאַחַר כָּךְ מֵת הַבֵּן, בֵּית שַׁמַּאי אוֹמְרִים, יַחֲלֹקוּ. וּבֵית הִלֵּל אוֹמְרִים, נְכָסִים בְּחֶזְקָתָן:


A house collapsed on a son and upon his father, or upon a certain person and upon those from whom he stands to inherit, and it is unknown who died first. If the son bore the responsibility to pay the marriage contract of his wife and to pay a creditor, and the son had no money with which to pay them except that which he might inherit from his father, and the father’s heirs say: The son died first and afterward the father died, and therefore the son did not inherit property from his father, and the creditors say: The father died first and afterward the son died, resulting in the son’s inheriting his father’s property, enabling the creditors to collect payment from the property even after the son’s death, there is a dispute with regard to how to rule. Since it cannot be determined who died first, Beit Shammai say: They divide the property between them so that the father’s heirs receive half of his property and the son’s creditors receive the other half. And Beit Hillel say: The property retains its previous ownership status. Since the last known owner of the property was the father, the property is given to the father’s heirs.

It seems that it is the opinion of Beit Shammai.
Usually, the Gmara does not tolerate that a Tana (and I would say especially a "late" one) would hold and opinion of Beit Shammai, and will try to make him say "they did not discuss this point, but this one" "...לא נחלקו על ... על מה נחלקו".
But I did not find that for this case!
Does Somekhos, Rabbi Meir's student, really hold like Beit Shammai?

See Tosfos Baba Basra 2a who explains that everyone agrees to the rule of ממון המוטל בספק חולקין when there is no one מוחזק. Both the standard argument between סומכוס and the חכמים, as well בית שמאי ans בית הלל, is when is someone considered מוחזק enough not to say the rule of ממון המוטל בספק חולקין. Hence, the case of בית שמאי is a different case, and סומכוס may acknowledge that the inheritors are מוחזק.
